# Apache Camel: How to get parameters sent to a Camel Servlet using a HTTP POST request by a smart way?

Tags: http, servlets, post, parameters, apache-camel

I'm writing a route that may receive a TXT file with some parameters using a Camel Servlet Component.
According to the [Camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/servlet.html) I'm supposed to have the parameter set in the header of the message. 
But in the the case of a HTTP POST it seems that the header is not populated as expected. 
 
I found that the body contains all the request, the file and the parameters.

Here is an example of content :

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryC9GDMXt2OAHARCZj
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upfile"; filename="user.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
hello world...
...
------WebKitFormBoundaryC9GDMXt2OAHARCZj 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userdata" testtest 
------WebKitFormBoundaryC9GDMXt2OAHARCZj 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id" 12344 
------WebKitFormBoundaryC9GDMXt2OAHARCZj--
```

Does someone know a way to get the parameters by a smart way?
Do I have to make my own parser in my processor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ericg,

If you use HTTP POST, the parameters are indeed set in the message body. Maybe you should implements a processor in your route to get the parameters from the body and set them in the exchange headers if it's what you need

Best regards,

Comment: @ericg how did u do it? See my question at http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Multipart-form-data-and-servlet-restlet-endpoint-td5758948.html#a5758976

Comment: @navaltiger I use a Tomcat container. I built my own parser to parse the body. For more information on the format look [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html).

Answer (score 1):

In the camel we can get HTTP post parameters, I am not sure to get the Content-Disposition. if we want to get Content-Disposition, we can write own processor method.
But sure can get the parameters, your mentioned body content is your uploaded files content.

```
from(HTTP_INBOUND_URL)
        .log("The message : ${in.body}")
        .doTry()
                .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        String templateId = exchange.getIn().getHeader("templateId",
                                String.class);
}
})
```

Where templateId is your HTTP post parameter.